# why does socket.dev give these warnings about my npm package?

Tags: npm, package

I am developing a npm package (phpstan-watcher).
Socket.dev gives me these 2 warnings:

1.

```
Manifest confusion  
SUPPLY CHAIN RISK  
This package has inconsistent metadata. This could be malicious or caused by an error when publishing the package.
```

2. 

```
Unpublished package  
SUPPLY CHAIN RISK  
Package version was not found on the registry. It may exist on a different registry and need to be configured to pull from that registry.
```

I don't understand how I can solve them.
Where can I find more information about what is wrong in my package?
Or how can these 2 warnings be solved?

https://socket.dev/npm/package/phpstan-watcher

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to have been fixed
maybe it just needed time to catch up with the last version